# How to validate a field in django DRF while it can have either email or phone as value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want to create a serializer that let users to login with their username or phone number,
Now if they use a phone number or username I need different validations.

I know that I can achieve this in the view, however, I'm looking for a solution to handle this situation in the serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DRF the validate method can be used for example with the following code:

```
if '@' in data['value']:
    # the validation for email should be done here
    validator = EmailValidator()
    validator(data['value'])
    return data
else:
    # here the mobile number should be validated
    pass
```